# installing webmin on an existing bind server

Tags: dns, bind, webmin

I want to use webmin to allow some less experienced administrators to easily create A records if they are needed.  Will installing webmin with the DNS module affect the operation of my currently running bind server in any way?  Or is it safe to install over the top?  Also, if I want to continue administering bind via commandline can I? or will the state of bind and what webmin knows about go out of sync?

Comment: If just want those people to create A record, it does not have much impact. I think it is easy to create or delete.

Answer (score 0):

Installing webmin will **not** change your dns configuration. Nevertheless **always** backup your config files before making **any** changes.

You can still administering binds via cli after you install webmin.